# error TS6044: Compiler option 'types' expects an argument

Tags: typescript, grunt-ts

i'm facing with the following error `error TS6044: Compiler option 'types' expects an argument.` when trying to set `"types": []` in tsconfig.json.

We are using **grunt-ts**

This is recommended by official TS documentation in order to get rid of the following errors: `node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts(14,9): error TS2403`

[Here is the link to TS documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)

**Specify "types": [] to disable automatic inclusion of @types packages.**

But instead of disabling automatic inclusion of @types i see error `error TS6044: Compiler option 'types' expects an argument.`

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've solved my problem specifying jasmine in types
 "types" : ["jasmine"]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using tsconfig.json passthrough with that parameter and grunt-ts.  Several of the new features in the TypeScript 2.x timeframe don't work very well or at all from the command-line.  Alternatively, you could try using the additionalFlags feature of grunt-ts and pass "" as the types value.  I'm not near a computer to test that, but it could work.